# Считывание текста в textarea

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, textarea

Вообщем, народ, у меня есть такая проблема: если в поле `textarea` вводят  слово "*чек/чеки*" c любым регистром и суммы (каждая в новой строке), например:

```
4,5 
6р. 
7руб 
34.67 руб 
65,3 р.
```

как-то все это дело считать. Но, я в JS плох, и к тому же, тут надо применять регулярку для маски сумм, а с этим у меня вообще большие проблемы. Обработчик должен быть на `keyup` или `focusout`. После, надо в функции все это дело проверять. Ну, как-тот так.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я конечно не уверен, но кажется эта функция может разбить текст на строки $('#text').val().replace(/^[\n\r]+|[\n\r]+$/g,'').split(/[\n\r]+/);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь, что в моём примере, Вы найдёте решение вашей проблемы. Я специально не стал сокращать и оптимизировать "регулярки", чтобы было нагляднее. Сложности нет никакой, код тоже небольшой, ибо половина - комментарии.

```js
var oTextInput = document.querySelector('.textinput');
var oTextOutput = document.querySelector('.textoutput');
var nTotalSum = 0;
// Добавляем обработчик к полю ввода
oTextInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let sTextValue = oTextInput.value;
  // Если слово "чек" или "чеки" отсутствует, тогда...
  if (!/(чек[и]?\s*\n)/gi.test(sTextValue)) {
    // Прячем поле вывода
    oTextOutput.classList.remove('show');
    // и выходим из обработчика
    return
    // иначе...
  } else {
    // Показываем поле вывода
    oTextOutput.classList.add('show');
  }
  // Обнуляем итоговую сумму для подсчёта
  nTotalSum = 0;
  // Удаляем пробелы и слово "чек/чеки"
  sTextValue = sTextValue.replace(' ', '').replace(/(чек[и]?\s*\n)/gi, '');
  // Находим суммы и передаём в функцию обработки
  sTextValue = sTextValue.replace(/^([\d.,]+?)[\D]*$/gim, fCalcSum);
  // Добавляем итоги и форматируем вывод
  sTextValue = 'Позиции:=======\n' + sTextValue + '\nИтог:==========\n' + (nTotalSum + 0.0001).toFixed(2) + ' руб.';
  // Выводим с разбивкой по разрядам
  oTextOutput.value = sTextValue.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
  // Прокрутка поля вывода вниз при появлении скролла
  oTextOutput.scrollTop = oTextOutput.scrollHeight
});

/* Обработка найденной суммы */
function fCalcSum(found, group) {
  // Приводим дробный разделитель к "точке"
  group = group.replace(/,/g, '.');
  // Если до точки нет чисел, то добавляем ноль в начало
  group = group.replace(/^(\.\d+)\D*$/gim, '0$1');
  // Если после точки один разряд, то добавляем ноль в конец
  group = group.replace(/^(\d+\.\d)\D*$/gim, '$10');
  // Если после точки нет чисел или отсутствует дробная часть, то добавляем точку с нулями в конец
  group = group.replace(/^(\d+)[\.\D]*$/gim, '$1.00');
  // Отсекаем разряды меньше сотых
  group = group.replace(/^(\d+\.\d\d).*$/gim, '$1');
  // Плюсуем к итоговой сумме
  nTotalSum += +group;
  // Возвращаем обработанную подстроку
  return group.replace(/^0+(0.)/gim, '$1') + ' руб.'
}
```

```css
.textinput,
.textoutput {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 1px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  font: bold 16px monospace;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 170px;
}

.textoutput {
  color: #080;
  left: -160px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  transition: all .8s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

.show {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.66, -0.28, .13, 1.71);
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textinput" placeholder="Введите 'чек', а затем позиции (каждая позиция с новой строки)"></textarea>
<textarea class="textoutput" placeholder="" readonly></textarea>
<div></div>
```

> Окно результатов появляется при вводе слова "чек(и)". Причём, его можно ввести, как сначала, так и по окончании ввода всех сумм.

*P.S. Если найдёте ошибки, то прокомментируйте - попробуем исправить)*

Answer (score 0):

Просто числа вывести?

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
const display = document.querySelector('pre')

textarea.addEventListener('input', function ({ target: { value } }) {
  const words = ['чеки', 'чек'];
  
  words.forEach(function (word) {
    if (value.toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
      const numbers = getNumbers(value)

      // console.log(numbers)
      display.textContent = numbers.join('\n')
    }
  })
})

function getNumbers (text) {
  return text.match(/[+-]?\d+((,|.)\d+)?/g)
}
```

```html
<pre>
  Введите чек/чеки
</pre>

<textarea rows="10">
че
7р. 
17,00 руб
10.00руб
текст: 1337рубб
</textarea>
```